# Print mysql_query in a text file

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a form in html with 2 fields: username and password.

There is also a database with a username and password predefined. There is a validation file too, that checks if user entered username and password correct. The validatioin code is this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$host="host_name"; 
$username="urn"; 
$password="pass"; 
$db_name="db"; 
$tbl_name="tbl"; 

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect");

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("could not select");

$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' 
AND     `password` = '$password' INTO OUTFILE log.txt LIMIT 1;");

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
session_register("username");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:file.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
echo '</br> <a href="/index.php" > Try again </a>';
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

What I need is to keep any username and password attempts someone makes into a .txt file. The INTO OUTFILE thing does not work but I dont know if I typed it correctly.

Any help appreciated. Thanx

Comment: for security reasons, mysql will NOT append to or overwrite a file that already exists. it can only create NEW files for the `into outfile` destination. you can use `file_put_contents()` or other normal filesystem operations to write out to your log file.

Comment: Just setup another query to keep track of that file, much like a counter.

Comment: off-topic but highly important: use PDO or MySQLi | mysql functions are out dated - sql injectable - getting removed from php

Comment: So apart from not salting and hashing the passwords in your database, you also want to store your users passwords in a text file and in the session. I wonder how your users feel about that.

Comment: @MarcB file_put_contents() must be insert in the form file or in the validation file?

Comment: @jeroen It is just an excersise for practice.. No one is getting hurt. Cheers

Comment: @user2607179 if you just need to log that someone try to login, you can make use of `error_log('username='.$username.' password='.$password)`. rather than having SQL creating a file which is madness

Comment: @meda and how will it be saved in a .txt file I want?

Comment: @user2607179 yeah why not, you can call it `log.txt` if you want.

Comment: @meda so it will be something like this? 
log.txt('username='.$username.' password='.$password)
WHere should I write this?
I am sorry for all these questions but I am a beginner :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), eventhough it is meant for error logging, you can still use it to achieve what you trying to do:

```
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

//log it to a text file
error_log('Login attempt-> username='.$username.' &&  password='.$password);
```

Comment: bool error_log ( string $message [, int $message_type = 0 [, string $destination [, string $extra_headers ]]] ) am I supposed to use this inside my code? Sorry I am confused

Comment: @user2607179 bro I wrote the code for you `error_log("Login attempt-> username= $username  &&  password= $password");`

Comment: I tried that but the login attempts info did not show up anywhere.

Comment: Oooohhh found it. It was in a subfolder of a subfolder of root. How can I change it though so it can appear in a subfolder of the html directory where all the main files are?
Thank you so much meda

Comment: Just figured out this too. I created a .htaccess file and changed the path in there. Thank you meda. I appreciate your help :-)